# Loop through each column name from one table and insert that name into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have two tables. One table has a list of 500 columns. Another table references each column name like this

```
Select Top 1 * from MyReferenceTable
```

Which returns the results

```
(69, 'FirtName', 1, NULL)
(69, 'LastName', 2, NULL)
```

Where 'FirstName' is the name of the column from an actual table.

So I want to fill this reference table with the column names from the other table as so

```
Insert Into MyReferenceTable
FileId, ColumnName1, ColumnOrder, DefaultValue
Values(69, Select ColumnName From OtherTable? ,
       Select Next Sequential Identity?, NULL)
```

My issue is how can I loop through the other table get the column name for each row, also insert an identity in sequentialOrder as ColumnOrder?

Typing out that insert statement manually for over 500 columns would take many moons.

Comment: This is a really bad design choice, and you should be avoiding it now. If you simply want the names of the columns in a table, you have the `sys.columns` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` objects, but you shouldn't be storing that information (as it's already available to you). If you're going to be using this data to try to create statements where you "replace" a column's value for a column's name, you'll (very) quickly find out that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This decision is out of my pay grade.

Comment: Then that person with that pay grade should know better.  It seems my assumption is right, which means that you're going to quickly find that you're going to be likely going down a rabbit hole of dynamic SQL, foreign keys without constraints, and/or awful queries plans due to a large amount of `LEFT JOIN`'s. You might want to have a look at some of the articles that discuss this type of design and their limitations/faults and raise them. if you can move the project in the right direction now you'll find things far easier in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible idea, but the answer to your question is straight-forward:

```
INSERT INTO MyReferenceTabel (FileId, ColumnName1, ColumnOrder, DefaultValue)
    SELECT 69, [name], [column_id], NULL
      FROM sys.columns 
     WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('MyOtherTable')
```

Basically you craft a SELECT statement that returns the values you want, and then just add the INSERT statement over it.

But again, this smells of a terrible design choice that will bite you in the end. But it's still good to know how to get this information, so I'm posting this example here.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed